# Vba offset to new sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I think im missing something, how can i write the output to a new sheet?

> ```
> Set rng1 = Worksheets("blad1").Range("B8", Worksheets("blad1").Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
> Set rng2 = Worksheets("blad2").Range("B1", Worksheets("blad2").Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
> For Each c In rng1
>     If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(rng1, c) > 0 Then
>
>         RowNo = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(c, rng2)
>         c.Offset(45, 0).Resize(1, 2).Value = Worksheets("blad2").Range("B" & RowNo, "C" & RowNo).Value 
>
>     End If Next c
> ```

Comment: What's `c`?  If you want the Blad2 worksheet range B#:C# to go onto worksheet called "MyWorksheet", then it'd be `MyWorksheet.Cells(1,1).Value = ...`  So, it looks like you should just add the `Worksheets("blad1").Cells().Offset(45,0)...`  the only thing is, can you clarify what `C` is, because you'll need to put a range in there (where I currently just have `Cells()`.)

Comment: c is a code in blad1 and blad2, if they are the same i want to copy the code and a field next to the code to a new sheet

Answer (score 0):

Untested:

```
Dim b1 As Worksheet, b2 As Worksheet, b3 As Worksheet, m

Set b1 = Worksheets("blad1")
Set b2 = Worksheets("blad2")
Set b3 = Worksheets("blad3")

Set rng1 = b1.Range(b1.Range("B8"), b1.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
Set rng2 = b2.Range(b2.Range("B1"), b2.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
Set rng3 = b3.Range("A1")

For Each c In rng1

    m = Application.Match(c.Value, rng2) 'no "WorksheetFunction"
    'm will be an error value if no match found
    If Not IsError(m) Then 
        rng3.resize(1,2).Value = b2.Cells(RowNo, "B").Resize(1,2).Value
        Set rng3 = rng3.Offset(1, 0) 
    End If

Next c
```

Comment: Where in de code does it write to result to a new sheet? -> "blad3"?

Comment: Exactly what should get written, and to what location?

Comment: 2 rows from worksheet "blad2" to worksheet 3 "blad3" if the code is in "blad1"

Comment: Two columns you mean?